# Gutenberg Block Validation Failed ( not expecting children )

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am developing a gutenberg Testimonials block, however when saving and trying to reload it gives me block validation failure, it seems to be expecting a block without children in the carousel-inner etc.

```
Expected:

<div class="wp-block-wf-testimonials"><div class="slideshow carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false"><div class="carousel-inner"></div><a class="carousel-control carousel-control-prev" href="#undefined" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="carousel-icon carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a><a class="carousel-control carousel-control-next" href="#undefined" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="carousel-icon carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a></div></div>

Actual:

<div class="wp-block-wf-testimonials"><div class="slideshow carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false"><div class="carousel-inner"><div class="carousel-item active"><div class="quote"> sdfas </div><div class="byline"> sdf </div></div><div class="carousel-item false"><div class="quote"> fsadfa </div><div class="byline"> asdfassdfadf </div></div><div class="carousel-item false"><div class="quote"> fdsafas </div><div class="byline"> sdfasdfas </div></div></div><a class="carousel-control carousel-control-prev" href="#undefined" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="carousel-icon carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a><a class="carousel-control carousel-control-next" href="#undefined" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="carousel-icon carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a></div></div>
```

Here is the attributes

```
attributes = {
        interval: {
            type: 'text',
            selector: '.slideshow',
            source: 'attribute',
            attribute: 'data-interval',
            default: 'false'
        },
        hideIndicators: {
            type: 'text',
            default: 'false'
        },
        viewMode: {
            type: 'text',
            default: 'edit',
        },
        testimonials: {
            source: "query",
            default: [{index:0, quote:"", byline:""}],
            selector: ".carousel-inner .carousel",
            query: {
                index: {
                    source: "attribute",
                    selector: ".quote",
                    attribute: "index"
                },
                image: {
                    source: "attribute",
                    selector: "img",
                    attribute: "src"
                },
                quote: {
                    source: "text",
                    selector: ".quote"
                },
                byline: {
                    source: "text",
                    selector: ".byline"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Full block code: https://github.com/Panguino/WF_Testimonial

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am new to Gutenberg, a bit new to react as well.  Go easy on me =).

Comment: Oy, i figured it out, it seems my selector for testimonials was off, so it was not able to find the markup.  instead of .carousel-inner .carousel i needed .carousel-inner .carousel-item .

Answer (score 4):

I think you found the solution, answering for future readers.

The **Actual** in the console error expects the previous HTML we saved in the `save()` method which is stored in the database currently and our block's `save()` method contains the new code. So, WordPress can't match the output thus resulting in a validation error.

Solution: You've to remove the current instance of the block and make a new one, it'll work. Though it's annoying, I hope the Gutenberg team would find a fix around this