# Gutenberg block validation fails (missing attribute)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, validation, wordpress-gutenberg

I made a Gutenberg block for my plugin but it doesn't work as expected anymore. It worked with the first version of Gutenberg and I don’t understand what changed since then.

I read some similar questions, but no useful answers:
 - [Wordpress Gutenberg block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752295/wordpress-gutenberg-block)
 - [Gutenberg Block validation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54311510/gutenberg-block-validation-failed)
 - [Gutenberg Block Validation Failed ( not expecting children )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53459420/gutenberg-block-validation-failed-not-expecting-children)

My problem in detail:

When I add the block into my content it looks perfect, also if I save the post I see the widget as expected.

The problem is that when I edit an existing article the block is broken:
https://ibb.co/6vHRcXC

The code looks good, I can see it in code editor: https://ibb.co/tDMGnPY

Updating the article the widget still works on frontend.

The console shows this warning followed by several errors: https://ibb.co/Gk80skq

**It looks like the attribute data-id is missing in generated code**, but I don't understand why.

I tried changing this attribute name (*in case [data-id] was a reserved word*) but nothing changed.

I tried changing the value of this attribute (*I need it to be an integer, but I tried adding uppercase, lowercase and underscore prefixes*) and nothing changed.

A bit of context: **I need a unique ID for every block created with Gutenberg**, no repetitions site wide **and I need to bring this ID to a JavaScript function on frontend**. Please tell me what I am doing wrong and if there is another way to accomplish that.

This is the complete JavaScript source of my Gutenberg block:

```
(function () {

    let iconSvg = wp.element.createElement('svg', {width: 20, height: 20},
        wp.element.createElement('path', {d: "M10,0C4.478,0,0,4.478,0,10c0,5.521,4.478,10,10,10c5.521,0,10-4.479,10-10C20,4.478,15.521,0,10,0zM5.039,9.226c-0.786,0-1.425,0.765-1.425,1.705H2.576c0-1.512,1.104-2.742,2.462-2.742s2.463,1.23,2.463,2.742H6.463C6.463,9.991,5.825,9.226,5.039,9.226z M10,18.049c-3.417,0-6.188-2.41-6.188-5.382h12.375C16.188,15.639,13.418,18.049,10,18.049zM16.387,10.931c0-0.94-0.639-1.705-1.426-1.705c-0.785,0-1.424,0.765-1.424,1.705h-1.039c0-1.512,1.105-2.742,2.463-2.742s2.463,1.23,2.463,2.742H16.387z"})
    );

    wp.blocks.registerBlockType('plugin-name/gutenberg-block', {
        title: 'CustomBlockName',
        icon: iconSvg,
        category: 'widgets',

        edit: (props) => {
            // @TODO: we need a unique ID for each block!
            this.myId = props.attributes.itemId || Math.floor(Math.random() * 8388607); /// Medium int max value is 8388607;

            props.setAttributes(
                {
                    itemId: myId
                }
            );

            return wp.element.createElement(
                'div',
                {},
                [
                    wp.element.createElement(
                        'div',
                        {},
                        [
                            wp.element.createElement(
                                'img',
                                {
                                    src: PluginNameGutenbergBlock.preview_image
                                }
                            )
                        ]
                    )
                ]
            );
        },

        save: (props) => {
            let dataId = props.attributes.itemId;

            return wp.element.createElement(
                'div',
                {},
                [
                    wp.element.createElement(
                        'div',
                        {
                            class: 'plugin-name-outer'
                        },
                        [
                            wp.element.createElement(
                                'div',
                                {
                                    'class': 'plugin-name-container-async gutenberg-block',
                                    'data-id': dataId,
                                    'data-type': PluginNameGutenbergBlock.item_type
                                },
                                wp.element.createElement(
                                    'div',
                                    {
                                        'class': 'plugin-name-' + PluginNameGutenbergBlock.use_template
                                    },         {},
                                    [
                                        wp.element.createElement(
                                            'img',
                                            {
                                                src: PluginNameGutenbergBlock.loader_url
                                            }
                                        )
                                    ]
                                )
                            )
                        ]
                    )
                ]
            );
        }
    });

}());
```

Comment: Don't know about WP, but trying a long shot here: Maybe try to set the *dataset* instead of data attributes, HTML elements have this attribute and each data-item is inside it. Maybe trying to set it as a JSON? Something like: dataset: { id: 11, type: 'type' }

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, now I discovered that _props.attributes_ is undefined for previously created blocks, that avoid attribute rendering. Still investigating.

Answer (score 4):

I understood my error, so I post this answer hoping to help other people.

When I create a new block I first generate a random value for attribute `data-id`:

```
/// Inside edit function
this.myId = props.attributes.itemId || Math.floor(Math.random() * 8388607); /// Medium int max value is 8388607;
```

Then I set this value inside the shared `props` object:

```
/// Inside edit function
props.setAttributes(
    {
        itemId: myId
    }
);
```

Then when I save the block I just created the script find the generated value:

```
/// Inside save function
let dataId = props.attributes.itemId;
```

So the block creation works well, but when I open an existing post my script wasn't able to find saved value, so the value of `dataId` inside the `save` function was `undefined` and the attribute `data-id` was missing. **This is the difference between saved block and generated block**.

The missing part was the `attributes` block which read values from saved code and make them available inside `edit` and `save` function.

**Here is my solution:**

```
wp.blocks.registerBlockType('plugin-name/gutenberg-block', {
    title: 'CustomBlockName',
    icon: iconSvg,
    category: 'widgets',
    attributes: {                                         /// <--- this block was missing
        myId: {                                           /// <--- this is the name of the property
            type: 'string',                               /// <--- this is the type
            source: 'attribute',                          /// <--- this is where is located the value I want
            default: Math.floor(Math.random() * 8388607), /// <--- this is a default value for new blocks
            selector: 'div.gutenberg-block',              /// <--- this is a selector for an element in saved block
            attribute: 'data-id'                          /// <--- this is the name of the attribute that contains desired value
        },
    },
    edit: (props) => {
        let dataId = props.attributes.myId; /// <--- this is always defined as the value of data-id attribute or as random number (as string)
        ...
    },
    save: (props) => {
        let dataId = props.attributes.myId; /// <--- this is always defined as the value of data-id attribute or as random number (as string)
        ...
    }
});
```